# comment not being submitted by my django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I want my users to be able to add `comments` under a `transfernews` [I am creating a sports related website], I tried this code, but for some reason I am getting this error `TypeError at /transfernews/ Field 'id' expected a number but got <Transfernews: Transfernews object (3)>.`,  I can add comments manually from the admin page but can't from the `comment form`. Can anyone please tell me how to fix my code?

My models.py:

```
class Transfernews(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    player_image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    player_description = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transfernews = models.ForeignKey(Transfernews, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.transfernews.player_name, self.user.username)
```

My forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

My views.py:

```
def transfer_targets(request):
    transfernews = Transfernews.objects.all()
    news = request.POST.get("transfer_id", None)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        new_comment.transfernews_id = Transfernews.objects.get(id=news)
        new_comment.save()
        return redirect(request.path_info)
    return render(request, 'transfernews.html', {'transfernews': transfernews, 'form': form})
```

My html file:

```
{% for transfer in transfernews %}



    <h2>Comments...</h2>

    {% if not transfer.comments.all %}
    No comments Yet...
    {% else %}
    {% for comment in transfer.comments.all %}
    <strong>
        {{ comment.user.username }} - {{ comment.date_added }}
    </strong>
    <br/>
    {{ comment.body }}
    <br/><br/>

    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <hr>
    <div>Comment and let us know your thoughts</div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ transfer.id}}">
        <div class="bg-alert p-2">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start">

            </div>
            <div class="mt-2 text-right">
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm shadow-none" type="submit">Post comment</button>

                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm ml-1 shadow-none" type="button">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `transfernews` is a _QuerySet_ (a collection) of `Transfernews` instances and not a single instance. When you write `new_comment.transfernews_id = transfernews.id` you would likely be getting an error...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `new_comment.transfernews = transfernews` instead of `new_comment.transfernews_id = transfernews.id`.

Also change `redirect(request.path_info)` to `redirect(reverse('<app_name>:<url_namespace>'))`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a name attribute to your hidden input, then only the hidden input data will be included in the form data.

```
<input type="hidden" name="transfer_id" value="{{ transfer.id}}">
```

and in your `transfer_targets` view make these changes

```
def transfer_targets(request):
    transfernews = Transfernews.objects.all()
    transfernews = request.POST.get("transfer_id", None)

    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        new_comment.transfernews_id = transfernews.id
        new_comment.transfernews_id = Transfernews.objects.get(id=transfernews)
        new_comment.save()
        return redirect(request.path_info)
    return render(request, 'transfernews.html', {'transfernews': transfernews, 'form': form})
```

Comment: It says `"Comment.user" must be a "User" instance`

Comment: can you share your user model(s)?

Comment: I imported it `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: Now it says `DoesNotExist at /transfernews/
User matching query does not exist.
`

Comment: @Abrar is your user logged in? Make sure your user is logged in before you try. Also add the `login_required` decorator on the view to ensure that only logged in users can access the page.

Comment: Now that I've logged in, this is the error `Field 'id' expected a number but got <Transfernews: Transfernews object (3)>`

Comment: in your hidden input the value should be ```{{ transfer.id}}```

Comment: Can you update the post with latest error traceback?

Comment: I've updated my view, I slightly changed it to run a `forloop` on `transfernews`

Comment: TypeError at /transfernews/
Field 'id' expected a number but got <Transfernews: Transfernews object (3)>.

Comment: Not this bro [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67586558/edit) your post and add the ***full traceback*** to the post, not in the comment section.

Comment: anyone to help me? :')

Comment: Bro we would like to help you, that's what we do, but you have to share us what we asked for..